# is there a way to keep recording after pausing expo-audio?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, expo-av

I'm unable to achieve this WhatsApp-like voice message recording, i want the user to be able to record and pause without limit as well as listen to what has been recorded, to finally send one whole audio.

> im using react native "0.72.5" , "expo-av": "~13.4.1",

**This is the Component:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { Audio } from "expo-av";

function AudioMessage({ ShowAudioModal }) {
  const [recording, setRecording] = useState(null);
  const [sound, setSound] = useState(null);
  const [isRecording, setIsRecording] = useState(false);
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  const [playbackPosition, setPlaybackPosition] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    startRecording();
  }, []);

  async function startRecording() {
    try {
      console.log("Requesting permissions..");
      await Audio.requestPermissionsAsync();
      await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
        allowsRecordingIOS: true,
        playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
      });

      console.log("Starting recording..");
      const { recording } = await Audio.Recording.createAsync(
        Audio.RecordingOptionsPresets.HIGH_QUALITY
      );
      setRecording(recording);
      setIsRecording(true);
      console.log("Recording started");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Failed to start recording", err);
    }
  }

  async function toggleRecording() {
    try {
      if (isRecording) {
        // Pausing recording
        await recording.pauseAsync();
      } else {
        // Resuming or starting recording
        await recording.startAsync();
      }

      setIsRecording(!isRecording);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Failed to toggle recording", error);
    }
  }

  async function stopRecording() {
    try {
      console.log("Stopping recording..");
      setIsRecording(false);
      await recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
      const uri = recording.getURI();
      setSound(uri);
      console.log("Recording stopped and stored at", uri);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Failed to stop recording", error);
    }
  }

  async function playSound() {
    try {
      if (sound) {
        console.log("Loading Sound");
        const { sound: playbackObject, status } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
          { uri: sound },
          { shouldPlay: true, position: playbackPosition }
        );

        console.log("Playing Sound");
        setIsPlaying(true);

        playbackObject.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate((status) => {
          if (status.didJustFinish) {
            setIsPlaying(false);
            setPlaybackPosition(status.positionMillis);
          }
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Failed to play sound", error);
    }
  }

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        position: "absolute",
        bottom: 0,
        width: "100%",
        height: 140,
        backgroundColor: "red",
        flexDirection: "column",
      }}
    >
      <View style={{ width: "100%", height: "50%", backgroundColor: "yellow" }}>
        {isRecording ? (
          <View style={{ justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
            <Text>0:00</Text>
            <Text>RECORDING AUDIO</Text>
          </View>
        ) : (
          <View style={{ justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
            <Text>PLAYING AUDIO</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={playSound} disabled={isPlaying}>
              <MaterialCommunityIcons
                name="play-circle"
                size={30}
                color={isPlaying ? "gray" : "#FF5421"}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          width: "100%",
          height: "50%",
          backgroundColor: "green",
          flexDirection: "row",
          justifyContent: "space-between",
          paddingHorizontal: 15,
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={""}>
          <MaterialCommunityIcons name="delete" size={28} color="#cfd1d5" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={isRecording ? stopRecording : toggleRecording}
        >
          {isRecording ? (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons
              name="pause-circle-outline"
              size={34}
              color="#FF2D21"
            />
          ) : (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons
              name="microphone"
              size={34}
              color="#FF2D21"
            />
          )}
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            width: 40,
            height: 40,
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
            borderRadius: 50,
            borderColor: "white",
            borderWidth: 2,
            padding: 5,
            backgroundColor: "#FFA121",
          }}
        >
          <MaterialCommunityIcons size={25} name="send" color="white" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

export default AudioMessage;
```

so far I have been able to just listen to the audio that was recorded before pausing when trying to resume it doesn't work anymore

Thank you in advance.